# display binary tree with php

Tags: php, binary-tree

i have table like this

```
id(AI)  user_id parent_user_id zone_id
 1        8          0         0
 2        8_L        8         L
 3        8_R        8         R
```

and so on i want to display this as binary tree,a nd i use recursive function.,but it seems like it is not given the correct put

code

```
 <div id='all' style='width: 250px;' align="center">8
<?php
//ChildNode(1);
function ChildNode($id)
{
global $wpdb; 
$prefix=$wpdb->prefix;  

    $check_parent_node= $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."user_reference WHERE parent_user_id =".$id." LIMIT 2" ));

    $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."user_reference WHERE parent_user_id =".$id." LIMIT 2" );
    //SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."user_reference WHERE parent_user_id =".$id." LIMIT 2
    //var_dump($user_count);
    if($user_count>0)
    {
        echo "<div>";
         foreach($check_parent_node as $chkpn)
        {
            if($chkpn->zone_id == 'L')
            {
                echo "<div id='left'style='float:left'>";
                echo $chkpn->user_id ."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div id='rigth' style='float:right'>";
                echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$chkpn->user_id;
            }
            ChildNode($chkpn->user_id);
            echo "</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";

    }
}


global $wpdb;
$prefix=$wpdb->prefix;

$user_parent_ids = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_user_reference " ));                 
$parent_ids_array;
$count=0;   
 foreach($user_parent_ids as $urd)
{

  $parent_ids_array[$count]=$urd->parent_user_id;

  $count++;

}   

$unique_parent_ids_array = array_unique($parent_ids_array);


foreach($unique_parent_ids_array as $upa)
 {
 if($upa!=0){
 ChildNode($upa);   
 //echo "<br>".$upa."<br>";
 }
 } 
?>
```

and this is the out put im getting

```
8
```

8_L      8_R
23_L      23_R
24_L      24_R
25_L      25_R
   26_R26_L
27_L      27_R
28_L      28_R
29_L      29_R
30_L      30_R
31_L      31_R
32_L      32_R